# Date time format : what is the format called?

Tags: flutter, dart, date, time, format

Want to know what type of Date format is this : `2022-08-12T01:47:24.856316` , `2022-09-15T08:32:38.490Z`
And how do i implement the current time to this format.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is known as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and you can parse and format it like this:

```dart
void main() {
  print(DateTime.parse('2022-08-12T01:47:24.856316'));
  print(DateTime.parse('2022-09-15T08:32:38.490Z'));
  print(DateTime.now().toUtc().toIso8601String());
}
```

Output:

```
2022-08-12 01:47:24.856
2022-09-15 08:32:38.490Z
2023-01-28T07:28:29.865Z
```